# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jcuda/driver/JCudaDriver

Tags: java, jar, cuda, jcuda

I am trying to set up JCuda and execute a Sample addition kernel. When I try to execute JCudaVectorAdd after compiling JCudaVectorAdd.java, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jcuda/driver/JCudaDriver
        at JCudaVectorAdd.main(JCudaVectorAdd.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

I have created a bash file with the steps I have performed to get to where I am:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This system has multiple Cuda instances, so we need to load the correct one
module load cuda-9.2

# Try to remove any jcuda zip files that may have been created previously
rm $HOME/jcuda.zip

# Get jcuda zip file from online, storing into $HOME directory
wget http://www.jcuda.org/downloads/JCuda-All-0.9.2.zip -O $HOME/jcuda.zip

# Remove the 0.9.2 directory in case it exists to get ready for a clean install
rm -rf $HOME/jcuda/JCuda-All-0.9.2

# Unzip the file and store within jcuda directory. NOTE: The version number will be maintained as jcuda/JCuda-ALL-0.9.2.zip, so multiple versions of jcuda can be installed using this script
unzip $HOME/jcuda.zip -d $HOME/jcuda

# Remove the zipped file now that it is no longer needed
rm $HOME/jcuda.zip

# Move into the newly create jcuda directory
cd $HOME/jcuda/JCuda-All-0.9.2/

# Get the example Main program for Vector addition from Jcuda site
wget http://www.jcuda.org/samples/JCudaVectorAdd.java

# Create a sample kernel
echo 'extern "C"'                                                   >  JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu
echo '__global__ void add(int n, float *a, float *b, float *sum)'   >> JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu
echo '{'                                                            >> JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu
echo '    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;'           >> JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu
echo '    if (i<n)'                                                 >> JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu
echo '    {'                                                        >> JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu
echo '        sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];'                                >> JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu
echo '    }'                                                        >> JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu
echo '}'                                                            >> JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu

# Create a .ptx file from the cuda kernel to be consumed by the Main java program later
# The sample Main program also performs this action, but we have it here as well
nvcc -ptx JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu -o JCudaVectorAddKernel.ptx

# Try to generate a class file from the example Main .java file
javac -cp ".:jcuda-0.9.2.jar:jcuda-natives-0.9.2-linux-x86_64.jar" JCudaVectorAdd.java

# Run the compiled executable
java JCudaVectorAdd
```

It appears that I am missing a step somewhere, although I am not familiar enough with java or cuda/jcuda to identify what I am missing. Can anyone point me in the direction of how to resolve this issue, whether it be additional steps are modifying the steps I have performed?

EDIT: It appears that I still need to reference the other .jar files in my execution (like they do in http://www.jcuda.org/tutorial/TutorialIndex.html basic test), so my last command may have been wrong. Changing it to the following has shown slightly different results:

```
java JCudaVectorAdd -> java -cp ".:jcuda-0.9.2.jar:jcuda-natives-0.9.2-linux-x86_64.jar" JCudaVectorAdd

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error while loading native library "JCudaDriver-0.9.2-linux-x86_64"
Operating system name: Linux
Architecture         : amd64
Architecture bit size: 64
---(start of nested stack traces)---
Stack trace from the attempt to load the library as a file:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JCudaDriver-0.9.2-linux-x86_64 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at jcuda.LibUtils.loadLibrary(LibUtils.java:143)
        at jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver.<clinit>(JCudaDriver.java:296)
        at JCudaVectorAdd.main(JCudaVectorAdd.java:38)
Stack trace from the attempt to load the library as a resource:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libJCudaDriver-0.9.2-linux-x86_64.so: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at jcuda.LibUtils.loadLibraryResource(LibUtils.java:260)
        at jcuda.LibUtils.loadLibrary(LibUtils.java:158)
        at jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver.<clinit>(JCudaDriver.java:296)
        at JCudaVectorAdd.main(JCudaVectorAdd.java:38)
---(end of nested stack traces)---

        at jcuda.LibUtils.loadLibrary(LibUtils.java:193)
        at jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver.<clinit>(JCudaDriver.java:296)
        at JCudaVectorAdd.main(JCudaVectorAdd.java:38)
```

Comment: What flavor of linux are you using to run your app?

Comment: Looks like a path issue.  You think you told the JVM where the JCuda JAR was, but it's not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to tell the JRE where to find the corresponding OS library to run cuda.  If you look at the output, it's stating it cannot find `libcuda.so.1`.

Find where in your filesystem these libraries are, and set your `java.library.path` property to point there.
`java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/cudalibdir/ <rest of commandline>`

If your system does not have the library, you might need to install it or compile it locally.

Disclaimer: I do not have experience with cuda specifically but have worked with other jars that require OS level libraries to function.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me. After searching through all of the /usr/ files on the server I am accessing for this library, I realized that I was connected to a system that did not have a GPU attached, which is where the issue came from. Switching to a different machine resolved this issue, although now I am getting a new `Exception in thread "main" jcuda.CudaException: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE` error. I will debug further for this issue and open a new question if necessary.

Comment: A side note, also @TreverWagenhals : The path to the CUDA shared libraries should, to my knowledge (although I'm not a linux expert) be added to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` during the CUDA installation. However, on a machine that does not even have a CUDA capable GPU, there most likely simply *is* no CUDA installation...